# (React/Redux) JSX ternary fallback isn't working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I got an array of users in state which at first is empty :

```
const initialState = {
  users: [],
  loading: false,
}
```

At first mount I fetch the users from an endpoint (with `useEffect`), and render them.

I want a "Loading Users.." fallback for the time it takes to load, 
but it doesn't work.

The JSX statement :

```
{usersFromState ? (
  <div className='usersContainer'>
    {usersFromState.map((user, i) => (
      <div className='messageBox' key={i}>
        user : {user.email}
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
) : (
  <div className='loading'> Loading Users... </div>
)}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `usersFromState` what's that? You need to check if the length is > 0 or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays - even if empty - are still *truthy* values, so the *"Loading"* div is actually never rendered.

You could e.g. check for the *length* of the users array.

```
{usersFromState.length > 0 ? ( ... ) : ( ... )}
```